# Add path with right angle between two nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to add an edge between two nodes but getting unexpected outcome.

I would like to add a path between nodes `g`, `h`, and `i` in a similar way that has been added between `a`, `b`, and `c`. However, when I try to do this I get an unexpected (to me) outcome -- the path goes backwards and not towards node `h`: the resultant lines that are produced are shown in red. It seems I have misunderstood the syntax; how can I correct it please?

[image]

code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}    
\usetikzlibrary{calc}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]    
     \node (a) {a};
     \node [above right of=a, xshift=2cm] (b) {b};
     \node [below right of=a, xshift=2cm] (c) {c};
     \node [right of=b] (d) {d};
     \node [above right of=d, yshift=-1cm] (e) {e};
     \node [below right of=d, yshift=1cm] (f) {f};
     \node [right of=e] (g) {g};
     \node [above right of=g, xshift=2cm] (h) {h};
     \node [below right of=g, xshift=2cm] (i) {i};  
     \draw (a.east) -| (45:20mm) |- (b.west);
     \draw (a.east) -| (-45:20mm) |- (c.west);
     % offending line
     \draw[red] (g.east) -| (45:20mm) |- (h.west);;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `(45:2mm)` is an absolute coordinate, which happens to be left of `g`. In the case of `a`, `b` and `c` you get the desired result because `a` happens to sit at `(0,0)`, the default position that gets used if you do not specify any, so `(45:2mm)` is right of `a` "by accident". The arguably cleaner way is to add `+` or `++` (in this case this does not make a difference since this is the second coordinate of the path) in front of all of the `(45:2mm)` coordinates.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}    
\usetikzlibrary{calc}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]    
     \node (a) {a};
     \node [above right of=a, xshift=2cm] (b) {b};
     \node [below right of=a, xshift=2cm] (c) {c};
     \node [right of=b] (d) {d};
     \node [above right of=d, yshift=-1cm] (e) {e};
     \node [below right of=d, yshift=1cm] (f) {f};
     \node [right of=e] (g) {g};
     \node [above right of=g, xshift=2cm] (h) {h};
     \node [below right of=g, xshift=2cm] (i) {i};  
     \draw (a.east) -| +(45:20mm) |- (b.west);
     \draw (a.east) -| +(-45:20mm) |- (c.west);
     % no longer offending line
     \draw[red] (g.east) -| +(45:20mm) |- (h.west);;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

That way you will not encounter bad surprises if you ever decide to move `a` around.

Finally let me mention that such diagrams can conveniently be produced with `forest`, which is based on `tikz`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={forked edges,text height=0.75em,text depth=0.25ex,grow'=0}
  [a
   [b
    [d
     [e
      [g
       [h]
       [i]
      ]
      ]
     [f]
    ]
   ]
   [c]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the explanation.